# Converting calculation string to int in Lua

Tags: string, lua, numbers

I'm trying to get a string with multiple numbers to a single int
like this:

```
x="5+5"  --amount of numbers is not constant
y=tonumber(x)
print(y)
```

The result of this is `nil` while it should be `10` (int). The only way I could solve this is by first searching all the `"+"` and `"-"` with `string.find()` then cutting it to all the necessary parts and from there just `tonumber()`. It feels stupid to code at least a hundred rows of code for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tonumber` can be used only on a string that is a real number, not an arithmetic expression.

You can load the string and run it:

```
x = "5 + 5"
func = assert(load("return " .. x))
y = func()
print(y)
```

In Lua 5.1, use `loadstring` instead of `load`.

Comment: Make sure you trust the source though; this can be used to run arbitrary code!

Comment: `setfenv(func, {})` should help to minimize the risk of running malicious code, shouldn't it? Is there a way that the code could still cause harm, even without access to any functions?

Comment: A better environment for evaluating an expression would be the `math` library, so that the user can write `cos(x)` instead of `math.cos(x)`.